# Live Bytes in iOS 7 increased by 59x approx. as compared to iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory-management, ios7

I have an app for iOS 6.x. I have tested memory allocation for this app couple of times using Instruments. Almost every time Live Bytes right after the app launch were **872 KBs** approx.

Then I ran this app on iOS 7 using Xcode 5-DP5 without doing ANY changes in the code. I saw the app was very slow as compared to iOS 6. I ran the Memory Allocations in Instruments just to find some dropping dead results. Live bytes right after the app launch: **49.8 MBs**, which approximately 59 times. Please see the screens if that might be of any help:

[image: iOS 7]

[image: iOS 6]

AFAIK nothing specific to memory has been mentioned in the iOS 7 docs. Moreover my app is ARC enabled. Does anyone know about this huge increase in live bytes on iOS 7? Is there a specific reason on iOS 7 for this? Or is it just because of beta release?

Comment: Be aware that iOS 7 and Xcode 5 are still under NDA which restricts your from talking about them outside of the official Apple Developers Forum.

Comment: D'oh. I didn't even know know this was a thing. Seriously we can't even talk about it?

Comment: By using the beta versions of iOS 7 SDK and Xcode 5, you agreed to an NDA, so yes technically you cannot disclose information about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the Developer release of the SDK. It got fixed when the GM seed version came in.